# Image segmentation to reduce the number of colors

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, k-means, image-segmentation

I have an image in 3D numpy array (each pixel has x/y coordinates and rgb tuple). I need to reduce colors of this image to certain value (from 2 to 1500) for cross-stitching pattern creation. As output I need a list of this colors.

Color quantization is not suitable in this case.

Now I use a stupid algorithm. Get list of all colors, sort by usage and cut first n colors (the most used). But this algorithm cuts off important underutilized colors, such as the lips or eyes colors on portraits.

So I have some questions:

1. According to this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) I chose Clustering method (K-means
   algorithm). Is it right choice?
2. If the answer is "Yes", then what library to use for Python3? scipy.cluster is ok?

Comment: K-means clustering is a good choice but you need to be careful on how you choose the initial cluster centres.  One method would be to randomly choose the initial cluster centres each time and re-run the algorithm multiple times and choose the result that minimizes the least squared error.  `scipy.cluster` is the best thing to use when you're using Python 3.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Wikipedia writes that there are some heuristic methods to choose the initial cluster centres, but does not lead them. Where can read about them?

Comment: There is no right way to do it.  The most popular way would be to randomly choose points within the data set as the initial cluster centres.  Andrew Ng's notes on Clustering through his Coursera Machine Learning course are an awesome start: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1geuoot5lbtt2ke/docs_slides_Lecture13.pdf .